# Terminal tab autocompletion like in Mac OS

Tags: command-line, mac, konsole

I could not find a screenshot, but i've seen a colleague of mine doing this:

he has a terminal open in his MacBook Air, starts typing a file name, presses Tab and is given a list of suggestions, like in linux, but has a possibility to move a cursor to select a suggestion. Then he presses Enter and the selected suggestion is entered automatically.

Is there such a think for Ubuntu? KDE?

Comment: Another shell?
http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/40/ZSH-Gem-5-Menu-selection/

Comment: You should ask your colleague what he was using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user @Melon.

The shell is called [ZSH](http://pixelstech.net/article/1348854378_9_reasons_to_use_Zsh):

> Mac has a built-in zsh version 4.x.x, you can directly use it, you can
>   also use homebrew to install the latest version 5.0.0.